# C# How can I run an msi installation package as a different user

Tags: c#, process, crystal-reports, installation, execute

I need to be able to install crystal reports on end user computers, but the network security wont allow it on a normal user login, so it has to be 'run as a different user' to install on each desktop.

I am trying to create a small application which will allow any user to install crystal reports..  so far I have:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName =   @"C:\cabs\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i \"C:\\Application.msi\"/qn";
        p.StartInfo.UserName = uname;
        p.StartInfo.Password = pword;
        p.StartInfo.Domain = domain;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;


        try
        {
            p.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(er.Message);
        }
```

When I try to run this code, I see the message "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

did I miss something out?

CHeers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSI is not a executable file in windows. You should call `msiexec` with you msi file as parameter

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName =   @"C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\cabs\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi";
p.StartInfo.UserName = uname;
p.StartInfo.Password = pword;
p.StartInfo.Domain = domain;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: thanks, all that was missing was @"i/ C:\cabs\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi";  just needed the i/ switch to start the installer... cheers